# Can you nest the <menu> tag? semantic HTML

Tags: html, semantic-markup, semantic-html

Is it okay to nest the `<menu>` tag?
eg:

```
<menu>
  <li>1</li>
  <li>2
    <menu>
        <li>2.1</li>
        <li>2.1</li>
    </menu>
  </li>
  <li>3</li>
</menu>
```

or shoud I use `<ul>` inside? eg:

```
<menu>
  <li>1</li>
  <li>2
    <ul>
        <li>2.1</li>
        <li>2.1</li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li>3</li>
</menu>
```

Have a good day and thank you!

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/menu: _"The <menu> HTML element is described in the HTML specification as **a semantic alternative** to <ul>, but treated by browsers (and exposed through the accessibility tree) as no different than <ul>. It represents an unordered list of items (which are represented by <li> elements)."_ - going by that, I think it is perfectly valid.

Comment: okay, I was a bit unsure when I coudn't find any eg of it. thank you very much :)

Comment: To add to what CBroe said, according to https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/grouping-content.html#the-menu-element, the `<menu>` element can be used "Where flow content is expected.", where flow content is defined as "Most elements that are used in the body of documents and applications are categorized as flow content." and amongst the long list is the `<menu>` item. So yes, you can nest them